# Sequence of Some Algorithms on Sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort, insertion-sort

i see in some midterm or final exam on MIT that the following question repeat and repeat in same manner.

we show an array in the some step of one sorting algorithm.

> > 5,3,1,9,8,2,4,7
> >
> > 2,3,1,4,5,8,9,7
> >
> > 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,7
> >
> > 1,2,3,4,5,8,7,9
> >
> > 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9

which of Insertion Sort / Quick Sort / Merge Sort / Exchange Sort is used?

how i find solution of this Questions?  ?

Edit: i think this is quick sort because each level some elements is lower than pivot and some elements is greater that pivot ....

Comment: **Exchange Sort** wow that's one fancy name for bubble sort right there

Comment: Which variant of quicksort would have 2 before 4 after a first step moving 4 down and 5 up? Dual pivot using 4 and 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases you can either a) find some pattern if you think there is one or b) go with simple elimination. Let's try elimination:

1) it cannot be insertion sort as insertion sort starts from the beginning and treats the range [0,k] as a sorted subarray of already checked values. Then it continues one by one so we **first would insert `3` before `5` etc** as we would at first treat `[5]` as a sorted subarray of size 1 and insert `3` into it as it's the next value in the whole array.

2) Merge sort would sort neighbor first as it would first recursively treat the whole array as single element arrays and then go back up the recursion tree and merge neigbors so more like this:

```
[3,5],[1,9],[2,8],[4,7]
[1,3,5,9],[2,4,7,8]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

`[]` shows which parts were sorted at each step.

This means that after one pass **neighbors will be sorted**.

3) exchange sort would also have a different ordering - the second line should start with `3` as you would swap `5` and `3`, then `5` and `1` etc in the first pass. So after one pass we would go from `5,3,1,9,8,2,4,7` into `3,1,5,8,2,4,7,9` if my bubble sort serves me right. We compare each pair and swap if element at `i+1` is greater that at `i`. This way the **last element will be the largest**.

4) as you fairly pointed out this is quick sort as in each step we can clearly see that the array is getting pivoted around a certain value 4, then you pivot the left half around 2 and the right half around 5 etc.

The parts in bold are the patterns I was talking about, now since you know them you can easily check which one it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be **quick sort**, not only because the evidence of partition, but also this interesting fact: for some level, only one part of the array changed.

Now let's discuss each algorithm:

**Insertion sort** will give you a pattern that the first few elements must be sorted, but obviously we don't have this pattern;

**Bubble sort (exchange sort)** will keep exchanging neighbors if the former element is bigger than the later element, and thus the last `k` elements will be sorted after `k` iterations. Based on these two facts, we won't have a pair of neighbor `(a, b)` that `b < a` exists after each iteration. However, the sequence doesn't follow this, say the term (3, 1) in the first sequence still exists in the second sequence.

**Merge sort** first splits the array into 2 + 2 + 2 subarrays and then merge it into 4 + 4 and finally a sorted array of 8 elements, so totally should take 3 steps, but we have 4 steps here, so won't be merge sort.

Comment: would you please describe more about bubble sort?